# Where i can find user login and password on visual studio online page?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I try to find username (and password) of my project on [visualstudioonline.com]

so, I try to push my repo into my project,but I cannot find login at least.

What is the login? my Microsoft live ID? or anything else?
Thank you!

P.S.

I have git string for commit to project like this: git remote add origin username.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_project.git

So, I type this to git command line- and they ask my username: username@gmail.com and password... but when I type Microsoft account password (from this login)- I have failed
[1](http://username.visualstudioonline.com)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

go to your project `https://projectname.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Projectname/`.
Click on your name in right upper corner and select edit profile.  A pop up will appear . In the pop up you can see `GENERAL, LOCAL, ECREDENTIALS, CONNECTIONS` 4 tabs . click under **credentials** . And select **Enable alternate credentials** and save . Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

You should use [this help link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd286572.aspx)

It takes 2 hours for me. I hope it will helps.